# pygame video system not initialized

Tags: pygame

I keep getting this error: "pygame.display.update() pygame.error: video system not initialized"
even though I initialised all pygame modules. Any ideas?
I'm using the latest version of pygame, python 3.8.5, I'm running the program in the the python shell and my OS is Windows.

```
import pygame, random
pygame.init()
win=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
loop=True


while loop:
    clock.tick(25)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button==1:
                pos=event.pos
                pos=(round(pos[0]/SIDE),round(pos[1]/SIDE))
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            loop=False
            pygame.quit()
    board.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What is your operating system? What is the Python and PyGame version? Which IDE do you use?

Comment: Try with `pygame.display.flip()` not sure that will work, but you still can try.

Answer (score -1):

Are you only getting this error when you quit the program? If so, Move `pygame.quit()` to the **end** of your file. When you exit the game, you call `pygame.quit()`, which automatically calls `pygame.display.quit()`, deinitializing the video (`pygame.display`) system. You then call `pygame.display.update()` which requires the video system to be initialized. Since you already deinitialized it, it raises the `video system not initialized` error.

Your code should look like this:

```py
while loop:
    clock.tick(25)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button==1:
                pos=event.pos
                pos=(round(pos[0]/SIDE),round(pos[1]/SIDE))
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            loop=False
    board.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```